# Rooted trees in TeX using tikz

Tags: tikz-trees

I'm trying to draw rooted trees in TeX. I found the following example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {root}
    child {[fill] circle (2pt)}
    child {[fill] circle (2pt)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My question is : How to fill the root too ? 
The following doesn't work :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {[fill] circle (2pt)}
    child {[fill] circle (2pt)}
    child {[fill] circle (2pt)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm trying to do it manually, i.e. by

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {$\bullet$}
    child {[fill] circle (2pt)}
    child {[fill] circle (2pt)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but it gives a break between root and edge.

How to do it in a simple way (without additional packages)?

Comment: Please always provide a complete, minimal example rather than mere fragments of code as a complete document we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the problem is much more helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing a node and a simple shape. They can look similar, but behave differently.

In order to fill the root, which is a node, you need to give it before the curly brackets, which are meant to contain the text, not options.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[fill, circle] {}
    child {[fill] circle (2pt)}
    child {[fill] circle (2pt)};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, I think `forest` will let you draw trees more easily. It's as easy as writing square brackets!

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
        circle,
        draw,
        fill,
        minimum width=2pt, % size
        inner sep=0pt,
        parent anchor=center,
        child anchor=center,
        s sep+=25pt, % distance between children
    }
[ 
    [ ]
    [ ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, but it this case the circle on the root is bigger than other. Second question : How to implement [grow=up] in this case ?

Comment: @mikis see edit. you can add `grow=north` to the options if you want the tree to go up.

Comment: (+1) for Forest. But shouldn't the children in the non-Forest code also be altered somehow?

Comment: @cfr Sorry for the delayed answer! I was intending to do that, but I see you already did it. :D

Answer (score 4):

Like [Alenanno](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307315/), I would recommend Forest but, if that's not an option, here's a non-Forest no-extra-packages-required solution, albeit one which requires more typing than Forest's syntax.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    my circle/.style={draw, fill, circle, minimum size=2pt, inner sep=0pt}
  ]
  \node [my circle] {}
    child { node [my circle] {}}
    child { node [my circle] {}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: not a Forest tree]